# Type missmatch - Vba from Access Data

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an error: Type missmatch. I want to get value from Database Access. I want to use Date() function from VBA.

Code:

SELECT TOP 5 Type FROM table Where Date Between #" + Date + "# AND #" + Date - 5 + "# Group By value1, value2 Order By SUM(value3) desc;

Comment: what engine is processing the query?

Comment: engine: Microsoft Jet

Comment: I meant is Access or SQL Server processing the query, but fair enough lol

Comment: It is Access :)

Comment: Is your date column actually a date data type?

Comment: Yes, date column is type date

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a field called [Date] ? Very bad idea: it's a reserved word.
In the meantime, you can try this way:

```
SELECT TOP 5 [Type] FROM table 
Where [Date] Between Date() and Date()-5 
ORDER BY value3 DESC
```

Your GROUP BY clause does not make sense in this context I think, nor does the SUM() in ORDER BY